# How do I enable enter key submit?

Tags: javascript

So two questions here: If I use `<input type="button" onclick="validate()">` then the enter key wouldn't work. However, I can use `type="submit"` but how would I invoke `validate()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the form validate on submit, which is better anyways:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validate()">

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can return `false` from your validation function to prevent the form from submitting.  The form will validate regardless of whether it's submitted via the return key or the button being clicked.